# using scientific notation in R

Tags: r, format

I'm currently using `printCoefmat` to print a matrix out and want to apply some formatting to the numbers.

I want to force scientific notation when the numbers have an exponent greater than 3.
I can't quite figure out how `scipen` works, Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: `options("scipen")` could be what you're looking for

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just type in a big number to get R to display unscientific notation.

```
options( scipen = 20 )
```

If that's not enough, make the number bigger...

### How does the scipen penalty work?

It is confusing, but the *penalty* is applied to the scientific notation version, as in R looks at how many characters it takes to print a particular string. It adds the value `scipen` penalty to the number of characters in scientific notation and if it is still less than the number of characters required to print the actual number then it will print scientific and vice versa. I hope this example will illustrate the point:

```
options( scipen = 0 )
options( digits = 6 )
>1e5
#[1] 1e+05    ----> 5 characters in scientific, vs. 6 for '100000' in normal
>1e4
#[1] 10000    ----> 5 characters in normal, vs. 5 for '1e+04' in scientific
options(scipen = 1 )
>1e5
#[1] 100000    ----> 6 characters in normal, vs. 5 + 1 for '1e+05' + scipen penalty in scientific
```

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? the documentation states "integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than scipen digits wider."

Comment: but I've know about this option, just don't quite know how to use it. There's a penalty, but a penalty to what? where's the cut-off value that it decides what to do?

Comment: @Phyx I've added an explanation. Heopfully this clears it up for you.