# How to get rid of scientific notation for factor produced by cut()

Tags: r, scientific-notation

How to rid of default scientific notation for `factor` variable? It is used by `R` when I have 3 or more digits in the current case.

I looked through other answers ([scipen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356530/using-scientific-notation-in-r) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r?rq=1), [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509346/r-displays-numbers-in-scientific-notation?lq=1)), but it seems they do not work for `factor` variables.

I use then this factor variable in the legend, and I need integer or fixed point values.

```
options(scipen=999)
plot(0,0, type="l", lty=1, lwd=4);

var1 <- c(3334,341,36,341,456)
cut1 <- cut(var1, breaks=2)
cut1<-levels(cut1)
cut1<-gsub(","," - ",cut1)
cut1<-gsub("\\(","[",cut1)
#cut1 <- as.character(cut1);
#formatC(cut1, digits="10", format="f")
cut1
```

> [1] "    [32.7 - 1.68e+03]" "[1.68e+03 - 3.34e+03]

And I want something like that:

> [1] "    [32.7 - 1680]" "[1680 - 3340]"

Comment: The issue is nothing to do with the variable being a factor. It's purely due to the `cut()` function, and the fact that it ignores `options('scipen'), options('digits')` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point where you have to specify what levels you are interested in, is a `cut` function. So easiest way is:

```
cut1 <- cut(var1, breaks=2, dig.lab = 5)
[1] (1685,3337.3] (32.702,1685] (32.702,1685] (32.702,1685] (32.702,1685]
Levels: (32.702,1685] (1685,3337.3]
```

See ?cut for more information.